# Behavior of variables initialized inside inline function

Tags: c, function, variables, embedded

I have a question about inline functions' initialized variables.
I initialized 5 variables (using `round()`, `ceil()`, and `fabs()`) inside a function but the problem was that the CPU takes about 1500 cycles to calculate their values.

Once I declared my function as inline functions it seems that the program and CPU no longer calculate these variables and also skip them in the debugger (despite working already fine as they were calculated before running the program or something). When checking the total cycles the 1500 cycles used for calculating them are gone now!

**Question:**
What's happening in my case? Why CPU ignores calculating variables in **inline** functions and calculates them in **normal** functions?

**Edit #1**: Here is what I mean:
for inline function when I enter the function it goes directly to the highlighted line of code as it's the first line, here's the number of cycles required to go to the highlighted line of code:
[image: inline function image]

and here is normal function, when I enter it it goes directly to initializing each variable line by line normally.
[image: Normal function image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please demonstrate

Comment: Post the code and how you make the measurements. The fact that some library functions are `inline` is irrelevant, the compiler can evaluate any pure code at compile time and reduce it to its result as constants in the object code. How much of that is performed for a given piece of code depends on optimisation settings and performance with thresholds determined by the compiler implementors.

Comment: Perhaps because the compiler can optimise an inline instance of a function for its context, which it cannot do as a function without knowing what is calling it.

Comment: I added 2 images explaining what I mean.

Comment: Posting images to depict what is happening in your code is not preferred.  How can someone truly discuss _"Behavior of variables initialized inside inline function"_ with anything but supposition without having access to the code being asked about?  Consider editing to post your code to get more precise answers to your questions.  (both here and in comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that some library functions are inline is irrelevant, the compiler can evaluate any pure code at compile time and reduce it to its result as constants in the object code. How much of that is performed for a given piece of code depends on optimisation settings and performance with thresholds determined by the compiler implementors.

In your case, it seems the compiler can optimise the computation of these initializers when you declare the function as `inline`, probably because you call it with constant or even literal values.  The intializers are probably computed at compile time and the resulting values are used in expressions as constants without even getting stored in the local variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, it seems like that's exactly what's happening, but I still cannot understand well. I've added 2 images above for the initializers and cycles count.
Would be appreciated if you explain more :)

But how can it be optimized if it has an argument to get (hard coded in program) and start calculating depending on it. I call this function as:

TIMER_delay(500);

Comment: To get a more precise and pertinent explanation, you must post the actual code as text so SO contributors can experiment with other tools such as godbolt.org compiler explorer.